# PHP & MySQL: Replace Image if the File Name (not file extension) is Identical?

Tags: php, mysql

For example if I uploaded "profile1.jpg" to my website, then later uploaded "profile1.png" or "profile1.gif", the new image should replace the old image if the file name is identical *even if* the *file extension* is different. My code to upload the profile image is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
                $fileNameNew = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination); /*Something like then_replace_all_files_with_this_filename (example) */
                $sql = "UPDATE profileimg SET status=0 WHERE userid='$id';";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location:index.php?upload=success");
            } else {
                echo "File too large!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error uploading your file!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Format not allowed!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this immediately before calling move_uploaded_file:

```
foreach(glob("uploads/profile{$id}.*") as $match) {
    unlink($match);
}
```

Comment: Works exactly as I wanted it! A++